# How can I prevent products in an E-commerce cart from incrementing in 2's?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I built an E-commerce site for pizza. It could be viewed here: https://chinomso1995.github.io/dodosPizza/.

I have created an orders page and On the orders page when you try to increment items, it increments in two's. I have gone through the reducer code I wrote and the context code and I seem to have written everything correctly. I can't pinpoint where the problem is coming from.

JSX code for my reducer

```
const Storage = (cartItems) => {
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cartItems.length > 0 ? cartItems: []));
}

export const sumItems = cartItems => {
    Storage(cartItems);
    let itemCount = cartItems.reduce((total, product) => total + product.quantity, 0);
    let total = cartItems.reduce((total, product) => total + product.price * product.quantity, 0).toFixed(2);
    return { itemCount, total }
    
}

export const CartReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "ADD_ITEM":
            if (!state.cartItems.find(item => item.id === action.payload.id)) {
                state.cartItems.push({
                    ...action.payload,
                    quantity: 1
                })
            } 

            return {
                ...state,
                ...sumItems(state.cartItems),
                cartItems: [...state.cartItems]
            }
        case "REMOVE_ITEM":
            return {
                ...state,
                ...sumItems(state.cartItems.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload.id)),
                cartItems: [...state.cartItems.filter(item => item.id !== action.payload.id)]
            }
        case "INCREASE":
            state.cartItems[state.cartItems.findIndex(item => item.id === action.payload.id)].quantity++
            return {
                ...state,
                ...sumItems(state.cartItems),
                cartItems: [...state.cartItems]
            }
        case "DECREASE":
            state.cartItems[state.cartItems.findIndex(item => item.id === action.payload.id)].quantity--
            return {
                ...state,
                ...sumItems(state.cartItems),
                cartItems: [...state.cartItems]
            }
        case "CHECKOUT":
            return {
                cartItems: [],
                checkout: true,
                ...sumItems([]),
            }
        case "CLEAR":
                return {
                    cartItems: [],
                    ...sumItems([]),
                }
        default:
            return state

    }
}
```

JSX code for the context

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer, use } from 'react';
import { CartReducer, sumItems } from './OrderReducer';

export const CartContext = createContext()

const storage = localStorage.getItem('cart') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart')) : [];
const initialState = { cartItems: storage, ...sumItems(storage), checkout: false };

const CartContextProvider = ({children}) => {

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(CartReducer, initialState)

    const increase = payload => {
        dispatch({type: 'INCREASE', payload})
    }

    const decrease = payload => {
        dispatch({type: 'DECREASE', payload})
    }

    const addProduct = payload => {
        dispatch({type: 'ADD_ITEM', payload})
    }

    const removeProduct = payload => {
        dispatch({type: 'REMOVE_ITEM', payload})
    }

    const clearCart = () => {
        dispatch({type: 'CLEAR'})
    }

    const handleCheckout = () => {
        console.log('CHECKOUT', state);
        dispatch({type: 'CHECKOUT'})
    }

    const contextValues = {
        removeProduct,
        addProduct,
        increase,
        decrease,
        clearCart,
        handleCheckout,
        ...state
    } 

    return ( 
        <CartContext.Provider value={contextValues} >
            { children }
        </CartContext.Provider>
     );
}
 
export default CartContextProvider;
```

JSX code for the Product Context

```
export const ProductsContext = createContext()

const ProductsContextProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [pizzaproducts] = useState(Pizza)
    const [sideproducts] = useState(Sides);
    const [dessertproducts] = useState(Desserts)
    const [drinkproducts] = useState(Drinks)
    return ( 
        <ProductsContext.Provider value={{sideproducts, dessertproducts, drinkproducts, pizzaproducts}} >
            { children }
        </ProductsContext.Provider>
     );
}
 
export default ProductsContextProvider;
```

JSX code for a section

```
const Sides = ()=> {
  const {sideproducts} = useContext(ProductsContext);
  const {addProduct, cartItems, increase} = useContext(CartContext);
  const isInCart = sideproducts => {
    return !!cartItems.find(item => item.id === sideproducts.id);
  }
  return(
    <div className={styles.Sides} id='sides'>
      <h1>Sides</h1>
      <div className={styles.SidesContainer}>
            {sideproducts.map(side=>{
                    
              return <div className={styles.SidesCard}>
                        <div className={styles.ImageContainer}>
                         <img src={side.image} alt="sausagerollone"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className={styles.SidesHeader}>
                         <div>
                          <h1>{side.name}</h1>
                          <p>{side.details}</p>
                         </div>
                        <div className={styles.SidesFooter}>
                          <h3>₦{side.price}</h3>
                          {
                             isInCart(side) && 
                             <button 
                             onClick={() => increase(side)}>Add more</button>
                            }
                         { !isInCart(side) &&
                         <button onClick={()=>addProduct(side)}>
                         <span>from ₦{side.price}</span>  
                         <span>Add to basket</span>
                         </button>}
                         </div>  
                        </div>  
                     </div>  })} 
        </div>
        </div>

  )
}

export default Sides;
```

In the increased case of the reducer code, I increment each item by one but it does increment by two in the app itself. This also affects the total price.

Comment: FYI `state.cartItems[state.cartItems.findIndex(item => item.id === action.payload.id)].quantity++` is a state mutation.

Comment: In spite of the state mutation your reducer appears to function correctly [codesandbox unit test](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-yalow-zm9pc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Findex.test.js&previewwindow=tests&theme=dark). Perhaps the action is dispatched twice, or maybe something else is happening. Can you get a working/running codesandbox that reproduces the +2 increment we could look at?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to go through the reducer @DrewReese. If you click the link and order something and then go to the orders page and try to increment what you have ordered, the quality increments by 2 instead of one.

Comment: Odd, I went to the link, selected a "Pepperoni Fresh", saw the cart count was 1, selected a second and saw the cart count was 2, then went to the cart with the (-) and (+) buttons and they both increment/decrement quantity by 1.

Comment: Try selecting more items. It increments by two. I have tried it on different browsers.

Comment: I've tried adding multiple *different* items, tried adding duplicate items, tried the same in Safari (versus Chrome)... I can't seem to be able to reproduce the incrementing by 2 in your live test site.